# Chart.js show negative value in the top half

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am creating a chart.js which has both positive and negative values

but how to make all values be on the top half
(ignore the if it's positive or negative when drawing but keep the label)

```
var tax_dash = new Chart(ctx_tax_dash, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: lable_set,
    datasets: [{
        label: "Tax in",
        data: total_tax_in_t_data__year,
        backgroundColor: '#0fd96d',
        // borderColor: sales_t_data,
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
      {
        label: "Tax out",
        data: total_tax_out_t_data__year,
        backgroundColor: '#0f81d9',
        // borderColor: sales_t_data,
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
      {
        label: "Net VAT",
        data: total_tax_in_out_t_data__year,
        backgroundColor: '#d96a0f',
        // borderColor: sales_t_data,
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
    }
  },
});
```

[image]

### EDIT

what I am trying to do

[image]

- **possible solution: is (multi-axis) dual y axis.[multi-axis example](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/master/charts/line/multi-axis.html)**

  - ~ issue: how to flip the axis so that the -100 be to the top and 0 be on the bottom
  - ~ issue: how to split the data set base on the (sign)

### OR

[image]

- **possible solution  2 : make all variable positive**
- @Gkiokan> solution: use the popup modifier to the showing values with negative

  - ~ ++ issue: how the function will know if the value is negative
  - ~ issue: the user needs to know that this value is negative in the label

Comment: its unclear, how can -600 be above 0? perhaps use `Math.abs`

Comment: the values are coming from a function so I can't control them so is there a was to make all values positive but keep the label negative @LawrenceCherone

Comment: I think this can be done with dual y axis not sure how to do it @LawrenceCherone

Comment: So, do you need to sort the data into + and -, and then graph both of them?

Comment: yes with both appearing in the top half and starting with zero on the bottom @VicenteC

Comment: So you should calculate the minim value of those negative values and then create a graph that has the minimum obtained as 0, then as @LawrenceCherone said, use Math.abs on your negative data set.

Comment: I added an image of what I am trying to do @VicenteC

Comment: Did you try to multiply the value with `* - 1` ? That would make `-600` into `+600`. Of course you need to modify the data first before putting it as chartData. I believe charts.js has also an popup modifier for the showing values which would allow you to modify the showing values, too if you need to.

Comment: This is solution 2 but i have an issue: how the function will know if the value is negative @Gkiokan

Comment: @MoazMabrok This is a good question. Actually this is pretty simple with some validation functions because you will have the `originalData` and `modifiedData` for the chart. So then you can verify the original value of that item before printing it out - based on the index of the item. You know what I mean? If you can provide me an working minimal example I can add you the nessesary functions.

Comment: @Gkiokan Thank you for the help and for sticking with the question greatly appreciate it  if you have a more elegant solution I will select it as the right one.

Comment: @MoazMabrok YW, checkout my answer which should work like an automatic solution for any similar use case. Also you have full control over the values with it. hf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you can have a data Set to save the orginal Data and the modified
Data and then use the values as you need. You can not trust the value characters. My solution will work kind cross over as you have control over both values.

I've made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xs705zno/23/) for you which demonstrates the orginal Data vs modified Data usage. Please click first on Modify Data which will then map the data, so you can see the work in progress. In your case you would modify the data before calling the charts.

Actually you will need just a couple of methods as followed:
`updateItemValues` to modify the negative values and put it to the other object
`tooltipCallback` callback for the tooltip to use the mapped orginal value

```js
let data = {
    modified: false,
    
    orginalData : {
        'tax_in' : [10, 20, -30, -40, -100, -50],
        'tax_out' : [-10, 10, 20, 10, -40, -70],
        'net_vat' : [-50, -9, -40, -20, -10, -90],
    },

    modifiedData : {
        // this modified data will be calculated before putting it in the charts        
        // for demo purpose we will just copy the values for now.
        'tax_in' : [10, 20, -30, -40, -100, -50],
        'tax_out' : [-10, 10, 20, 10, -40, -70],
        'net_vat' : [-50, -9, -40, -20, -10, -90],
    },

    updateModifiedData(){
        // loop though the orginal Data 
        Object.keys(this.orginalData).forEach( (item, indexx) => {
            console.log('modifying item chart data for: ', item)
            this.updateItemValues(item)
        })
        
        this.modified = true 
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'modified'
    },

    updateItemValues(dataKey){
        let temp = []
        this.orginalData[dataKey].forEach( (value, index) => {
            console.log('- validating ', dataKey, 'index: ', index, '; value: ', value)

            // if we have a negative value, just multiply by -1 so get it positive
            if(value <= 0){
                value = value * -1
            }

            // add to the temporary variable
            temp.push(value)
        })

        // put the modified data to some place to have it saved
        this.modifiedData[dataKey] = temp
        console.log('-- final data modded ', temp)
    },
    

    tooltipCallback(tooltipItem, chartData) {             
        // find reference values              
        let index = tooltipItem.index 
        let dataIndex = tooltipItem.datasetIndex

        // find the name of dataset 
        let key = chartData.datasets[dataIndex].name

        // validate or whatever with the orginal value
        let orginalValueOfItem  = data.orginalData[key][index]
        let modifiedValueOfItem = data.modifiedData[key][index]

        // Modify your final tooltip here
        return 'Orginal Value: ' + orginalValueOfItem + ' ; Modified Value: ' + modifiedValueOfItem
    }

}
```

### How can you use this solution?

Pretty simple.

- Copy that `data` Object in your code.
- Fill the `data.orginalData` value with your orginal charts data based on `key`

  - example `data.orginalData.tax_in = [...]`
- In your datasets add `name` property with the corresponding `key`
- Extend the Charts options with the `tooltipCallback`
- Call `data.updateModifiedData()` to get the modified data
- Checkout the jsFiddle for reference if you need to.
- Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 2

I did it this morning user what Math.abs from **@Lawrence** comment and "popup modifier" from **@Gkiokan** comment as well as this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omamesh/f0r7akvu/7/)

Thank you very much for the help. Chatting with smarter people rubs off on you :)

```
               total_tax_in_t_data_portal_month_year = [Math.abs(12),Math.abs(-234),Math.abs(234)];
                total_tax_in_t_data_portal_month_year_sign = [12,-234,234];
                var tax_dash_portal = new Chart(ctx_tax_dash_portal, {
                    type: "bar",
                    data: {
                        labels: lable_set,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: "VAT In",
                                data: total_tax_in_t_data_portal_month_year,
                                sign: total_tax_in_t_data_portal_month_year_sign,
                                backgroundColor: "#0fd96d",
                                // borderColor: sales_t_data,
                                borderWidth: 1,
                            },
                            {
                                label: "VAT Out",
                                data: total_tax_out_t_data_portal_month_year,
                                sign: total_tax_out_t_data_portal_month_year_sign,
                                backgroundColor: "#0f81d9",
                                // borderColor: sales_t_data,
                                borderWidth: 1,
                            },
                            {
                                label: "Net VAT",
                                data: total_tax_t_data_portal_month_year,
                                sign: total_tax_t_data_portal_month_year_sign,
                                backgroundColor: "#d96a0f",
                                // borderColor: sales_t_data,
                                borderWidth: 1,
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    options: {
                        legend: {
                            display: true,
                        },
                        tooltips: {
                            enabled: true,
                            callbacks: {
                                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                                    var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                                    var val = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                                    var sign = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].sign[tooltipItem.index];
                                    if(sign < 0){
                                        return label + ": -" + val;
                                    }else{
                                        return label + ': ' + val;
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                          }
                        
                    },
                });
```

`total_tax_in_t_data_portal_month_year` is an example as the values come from a function

`Math.abs` is used to remove the negative sign

then I added `sign` to the `datasets` for essay access

`tooltips` callbacks is called on every variable so I added the if statement there
to add `-` if `sign < 0` and do nothing if not